# #c Wpf DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class ClsStationModel

```
public class ClsStationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Station> Stations { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This class contains another class Station

```
public class Station 
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsHistoricalServer { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<NetworkInterface> NetWorkInterface { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to bind a combobox to Station. I did it like that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ClsStationModel StationModel = new ClsStationModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = StationModel;
    }

    ...
}
```

And in the xaml it did that and that works:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Stations, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Now, I would like to add a textbox that display the Comment which is in my Station class and depends to which element is selected in the combo box.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="188,81,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path= /Comment}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

But this do not work.
Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: In the typical MVVM approach there would be a SelectedStation property in ClsStationModel, to which the ComboBox's SelectedItem would be bound. The Text would then be bound with `{Binding SelectedStation.Comment}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do I set the SelectedStation property?

Comment: As said "to which the ComboBox's SelectedItem would be bound": `<Combobox ... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStation}"/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either bind to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="combo" ... />

    <TextBox ... Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Comment, ElementName=combo}" />
```

...or bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` and the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to a `Station` property of your view model, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of this property.

Comment: But I really don't know how the PropertyChanged works!!!

Comment: It's well explained in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx